# Find matching value in other table and copy the adjacent value back to the first table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for an IF-formula to find a text in another table, and to copy the value in the adjacent cell (next column) to the first table.

[image: First table where formula should be put in]

[image: Second table with data]

So to make it clear - the text from the first column should be found in the the first column of the second table, the value of the adjacent cell in the second table should then show up in the first table second column.

Comment: I think you are after **VLOOKUP** function. Have a go and update your post if you come across any problems.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What did you try exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i understood your question you just need the amount from table 2 to table 1 based on the first column number.

If **Yes** the follow the below method, If **No** please elaborate your question with some more example.

If The Formula Not Worked Please Do Delimiting The A Column by Below Short Code and Then Apply The Lookup Formula

**Formula Used (Cell B2) and Applied For Entire B Column**

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Table 2'!A:B,2,0)
```

**Alt** => **D** => **E** => **Next** => **Next** => **Finish**

Here is the View of Table 1 and applied formula to take the matching amount from table 2
based of ID column.

[image]

**Table 2 View:**

[image]

**Explanation Of the Formula**

[image]